# OnDraw Android (monodroid)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, ondraw

Can someone explain to me how to implement the onDraw function. I also like to know When is this function called. (i'm using Monodroid so if it could be explained using c# examples)

I'm trying to make a custom view with a graph on it (on a canvas) but it all points to it that i need to implement the onDraw function.

So if someone can make that clear to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDraw()` is called when you call invalidate().

I suggest you search for tutorials on how canvases work. Here's a place to get you started: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. For me, I was missing the `override` keyword in front of the function. This is equivalent to Java's `@override` annotation :)

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
...
}
```